# Connecting to MSMQ, the "proper" way?

Tags: c, winapi, msmq

I'm trying to connect to MSMQ and send some messages. Unfortunately, there is "previous art" in the project on how this is done and I'm supposed to mimick it. The way this previous app is connecting is the following:

```
if (MSMQ in workgroup mode)
{
    connect via FormatName;
}
else
{
    if (connected to network)
        connect via PathName;
    else
        connect via GUID (as FormatName)
}
```

Is all this really necessary? Shouldn't a proper FormatName be enough to connect to a queue?

Additionally, the "connected to network" is detected by calling `NetGetDCName()` which is marked as obsolete in my MSDN, adding to my confusion on why is the app connecting this way.

**TL;DR**: Is the above logic for connecting: wrong, obsolete or correct? Can I simplify this by simply using FormatName to connect in all cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is determining whether the domain is available by looking for the domain controller. If the domain is not available then MSMQ is assumed to be working in non-domain - or workgroup - mode.

Domain mode allows the use of public queues and pathname addressing.
Workgroup mode instead uses private queues and formatname addressing (although this is a simplification).

So the code is really determining the mode of message addressing to be used.

There is not enough information about the environment to say if you can just use formatname for all cases.

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: So basically, my safest bet is to simply do it the same way they did? Even using the obsolete function? I have asked about the environment, and they said it _should_ be a workgroup, but I'd still need to cover all my bases (I'm very wary of "should"s:)).

Comment: The obselete code is not part of MSMQ so I can't say. I expect it should work as the PDC emulator in the domain would respond. I'm guessing the code is from Windows NT4 time.
FormatName addressing can connect to anything so you should be OK standardising on that.

Comment: If FormatName is that good, that's all I need! Thanks for your help!